# SSH/SCP works but not wget

Tags: ssh, firewall, scp, wget

There are two machines:

**Build:** Using jenkins to get code and build war files

**Deploy:** used for deploying the war files to a tomcat server for testing.

I am trying to do automatic updates for the war files from the **Build** machine to the **deploy** machine.

I was going to use wget to get the lastSuccessfulBuild of the wars that I need for each update. The *lastSuccessfulBuild* is a hyperlink that when clicked downloads the war file.

When I try to use WGET, it sits there and then times out after a period of time.

This is using wget from the **Deploy** machine to get the files from the **Build** machine.

I can SSH from deploy to **Build**. I can SCP but it requires a password which makes automation kind of difficult.

I assume that **Build** has some firewall issues.

I am looking for solutions and how to diagnose this problem

Both systems are Centos/Red Hat

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols.

Whereas `ssh/scp` uses port 22. Most likely you don't have a web- or ftp server setup on the build machine.

The easiest solution for you would be to setup key based ssh authentication.